# Decode base 64 to ASCII

Tags: php

I have to decode a base 64 string to a ASCII the problem is that the string is 5482768 in length and for some reason when trying to convert it, it doesn't work.

This is the first thing I tried:

```
$var=base64_decode($str);
```

Then I came up with the idea of writing the string in a file, then read it and transform it, like so:

```
$myfile = fopen("file2.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = $str;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);

$myfile = fopen("file2.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$string= fread($myfile,filesize("file2.txt"));
fclose($myfile);
print_r(base64_decode($string));
```

Also dind't work.

My hypothesis here is that it doesn't work because of the length of the string, when I save it to the file the size is about 5,355 kb, it's to big.

What can I do to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show this problem file (using https://gist.github.com for example)?

Comment: "Doesn't work" means what exactly? Perhaps your script simply runs out of memory, do you have proper error reporting enabled? Writing the data to a file, only to read it back and then again pass it _as a string_ to base64_decode is likely not going to change much, hm?

Comment: I mean, of course it was stupid of me thinking about that, but I didn't want to ignore an idea. "doesn't work" means that it shows nothing in screen, I have the: ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); and also shows nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since base 64 encoding stores 6 bits of original information per char - you can try to read your file in chunks of size that is multiplier of 8 and decode it piece by piece.

Comment: _6_ bits, not 5. (2 to the power of 6 is 64, hence the name.) But yeah, apart from that, that would have been my suggestion, too. Multiples of 6 divisible by 8 is what you want to split on though. (F.e. 2 bytes, 16 bit, would be divisible by eight - but that would not give you a "full set" of 6-bit characters, so decoding will likely fail. Plus, you'd be missing the first 4 bits of the next character.)

Comment: @CBroe yes, 6 bits, my bad, fixed